# Dart Language: observable

Tags: css, web-applications, dart

I have two table rows at an HTML file. When the first row gets clicked, it changes its styling via classes.add("active_style"). If the second row gets clicked, I would like to clear the first row styling.

I know that I can just write...

```
querySelector("#first_row_div").classes.clear();
```

... in order to clear the first row class (and then resetting its style), but in a bigger code I think that observable would be the best fit.

I don't know if observable works for this. But, if it does, how can I do that?

EDIT/UPDATE: I think that the right question is "is there any way to run a function when a variable gets changed?".

Thanks for the help!

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by observable. In Polymer you can bind the class attribute of an element to a field in the elements class and you can declare the binding in the HTML markup. When the value changes all bound attributes get updated automatically. Your use case is so simple that I'm not sure it this is worth using this technique. If you use Polymer anyway then it's a different case.

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer You're right. It was confusing. I have updated the question.

Answer (score 0):

You can make a getter/setter for a field and run your function in the setter.

```dart
class MyClass {

  String _cssClass;
  String get cssClass => _cssClass;
  set cssClass(String newClass) {
    _cssClass = newClass;
    updateDom();
  }

  void updateDom() {
    // do important work here
  }
}
```

You can use a model class that extends `Observable`.
Here you have to call `dirtyCheck()` to make `Observable` check for changes and notify listeners.

Dart also offers the ChangeNotifier mixin. Here you don't need to call any method for dirty-checking. When changes are made listeners are invoked.

A simple example I wrote a while ago while examining the functionality

```dart
import 'package:observe/observe.dart';

class Notifiable extends Object with ChangeNotifier {
  String _input = '';

  @reflectable
  get input => _input;

  @reflectable
  set input(val) {
    _input = notifyPropertyChange(#input, _input, val + " new");
  }

  Notifiable() {
    this.changes.listen((List<ChangeRecord> record) => record.forEach(print));
  }
}

class MyObservable extends Observable {
  @observable
  String counter = '';

  MyObservable() {
    this.changes.listen((List<ChangeRecord> record) => record.forEach(print));
  }
}

void main() {
  var x = new MyObservable();
  x.counter = "hallo";
  Observable.dirtyCheck();

  Notifiable notifiable = new Notifiable();
  notifiable.input = 'xxx';
  notifiable.input = 'yyy';
}
```